# Obtain an array of steps from discrete spikes or peaks using numpy vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array of spikes or peaks like this:

```
peaks = [0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0]
```

and I want to *hold* the peaks, to obtain the following steps:

```
steps = [0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 15, 15]
```

I am concerned about speed (this is for image analysis on large arrays (1000**3)), so I can't use for-loops or list comprehensions.  It really must be vectorized.  In a for-loop this is obviously trivial, but vectorization is vexing me! (Almost-pun intended)

Also, because it will be applied to 2D and 3D arrays/images, a solution that only applies to a 1D list is not sufficient.  It will operate on *only 1 axis*, but it must be able to work across additional axes.  By this I mean:

```
peaks = [[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
         [0, 4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0]
         [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 9, 0]]
```

should become:

```
steps = [[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6]
         [0, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8]
         [3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9]]
```

I feel like there *must* be some numpy function that does this but cannot seem to find it.  I'm wishing for a function called `hold_peaks` or something like that.

I have been stuck thinking about `cumsum` which does create steps, and works on the first step, but makes the subsequent steps too high.  I have also thought about `add.at` but can't find a way to create the indices.

**Notes**

In my planned use case, I expect the peak heights to always be increasing, so a solution that does this is ok for me:

```
peaks = [0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0]
steps = [0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7]
```

but I imagine it might be nice to optionally do this:

```
peaks = [0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0]
steps = [0, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 7]
```

as in hold the most recent peak, even if lower than the preceding one.

Comment: In your second example, shouldn't the last row be `[3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 9, 9]`?

Comment: `np.maximum.accumulate(peaks, -1)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer You're comment is the correct answer.  Many thanks.  I have recently been learning to use the `at` feature, but have not yet dabbled with `accumulate`.  You should post this as answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @miradulo You are correct and I fixed it

Comment: @miradulo and yes it does seem like a duplicate.  Sorry.  I didn't even know what keywords to use when asking my question...but `accumulate` would've probably been enough had I known.

Comment: @2cynykyl No worries! It's a well-asked question, and knowing what to search for can be tricky.

Comment: @2cynykyl: Since no one has posted an answer yet, maybe alter your question to focus on the optional behavior. AFAIK, that's an interesting question with no duplicate.

Comment: @2cynykyl it so happens that I have a solution or two for your optional question, but it doesn't fit as a comment. So if you are interested you'd indeed have to make a new question ;-)