# Convert an array of peaks to a series of steps that represent to most recent peak value

Tags: numpy

Given an array of peaks like this:

```
peaks = [0, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 7, 0]
```

How can I create an array of steps that indicate the most recent peak value, like this:

```
steps = [0, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7]
```

Requirements:

- This will be used for image analysis on large 3D images (1000**3) so needs to be fast, meaning no for loops or list comprehensions...only numpy vectorization.
- The example I gave above is a linear list, but this needs to apply equally well to ND images.  This means doing the operation along a single axis, but allowing for multiple axes as the same time.

---

**Note**

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581855/obtain-an-array-of-steps-from-discrete-spikes-or-peaks-using-numpy-vectorization) that turned out to be a dupe (easily solved with `scipy.maximum.accumulate`), but my question also contained an optional 'would be nice if' twist, as outlined above.  It turns out that I actually have a need for this second behavior as well, so I'm re-posting just this part.

Comment: If it has to be fast, C is a better option than python. Fortran arguably better than either.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Correct you are, and +1 for giving props to Fortran...but there is also the issue of 'fast to code' as well.  Besides a good numpy implementation always surprises me for speed.

Comment: Numpy is coded mostly in C, and designed for speed, so it's not that surprising. There's still a good amount of overhead from interactions with python though.

Comment: Is Numba or Cython not an option for you? This would be most likely faster than any vectorized approach and much easier to code.

Comment: @max9111 _"and much easier to code"_ Debatable. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that handles ND and can detect "broad peaks" like `..., 0, 4, 4, 4, 3, ...` but not `..., 0, 4, 4, 4, 7, ...`.

```
import numpy as np
import operator as op

def keep_peaks(A, axis=-1):
    B = np.swapaxes(A, axis, -1)
    # take differences between consecutive elements along axis
    # pad with -1 at the start and the end
    # the most efficient way is to allocate first, because otherwise
    # padding would involve reallocation and a copy
    # note that in order to avoid that copy we use np.subtract and its
    # out kwd
    updown = np.empty((*B.shape[:-1], B.shape[-1]+1), B.dtype)
    updown[..., 0], updown[..., -1] = -1, -1
    np.subtract(B[..., 1:], B[..., :-1], out=updown[..., 1:-1])
    # extract indices where the there is a change along axis
    chnidx = np.where(updown)
    # get the values of the changes
    chng = updown[chnidx]
    # find indices of indices 1) where we go up and 2) the next change is
    # down (note how the padded -1's at the end are useful here)
    # also include the beginning of each 1D subarray
    pkidx, = np.where((chng[:-1] > 0) & (chng[1:] < 0) | (chnidx[-1][:-1] == 0))
    # use indices of indices to retain only peak indices
    pkidx = (*map(op.itemgetter(pkidx), chnidx),)
    # construct array of changes of the result along axis
    # these will be zero everywhere
    out = np.zeros_like(A)
    aux = out.swapaxes(axis, -1)
    # except where there is a new peak
    # at these positions we need to put the differences of peak levels
    aux[(*map(op.itemgetter(slice(1, None)), pkidx),)] = np.diff(B[pkidx])
    # we could ravel the array and do the cumsum on that, but raveling
    # a potentially noncontiguous array is expensive
    # instead we keep the shape, at the cost of having to replace the
    # value at the beginning of each 2D subarray (we do not need the
    # "line-jump" difference but the plain 1st value there)
    aux[..., 0] = B[..., 0]
    # finally, use cumsum to go from differences to plain values
    return out.cumsum(axis=axis)

peaks = [0, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 7, 0]

print(peaks)
print(keep_peaks(peaks))

# show off axis kwd and broad peak detection
peaks3d = np.kron(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 6, 3)), np.ones((1, 2, 1), int))

print(peaks3d.swapaxes(1, 2))
print(keep_peaks(peaks3d, 1).swapaxes(1, 2))
```

Sample run:

```
[0, 5, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 7, 0]
[0 5 5 3 3 3 3 7 7]
[[[5 5 3 3 1 1 4 4 9 9 7 7]
  [2 2 9 9 3 3 4 4 3 3 7 7]
  [9 9 0 0 2 2 5 5 7 7 9 9]]

 [[1 1 3 3 9 9 3 3 7 7 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 4 4 5 5 0 0 3 3]
  [5 5 5 5 8 8 1 1 2 2 7 7]]

 [[6 6 3 3 8 8 2 2 3 3 2 2]
  [6 6 9 9 3 3 9 9 3 3 9 9]
  [1 1 5 5 7 7 2 2 7 7 1 1]]]
[[[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 9 9 9 9]
  [2 2 9 9 9 9 4 4 4 4 7 7]
  [9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]]

 [[1 1 1 1 9 9 9 9 7 7 7 7]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 3 3]
  [5 5 5 5 8 8 8 8 8 8 7 7]]

 [[6 6 6 6 8 8 8 8 3 3 3 3]
  [6 6 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9]
  [1 1 1 1 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7]]]
```

Comment: This is pretty amazing, but in a 'almost magic' kind of way...could you sprinkle a few comments in there to explain how it works? :-)

Comment: @2cynykyl Done. Hope it helps.